# Android Retrofit connect JAVA socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, retrofit

How to use retrofit for Java server socket connection.
My server having JAVA Server Socket. 
and wanted to send request from android using Retrofit.
How to make connection and send - received data over Java socket

Comment: Retrofit is not designed for sockets.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the way that you can connect to your web service through Retrofit library. You can use this sample to do all ever you want:

1-First you need create a communicator class(to do all send-receive process)

```
public class Communicator {
    private static  final String TAG = "Communicator";
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/retrofit";

     public void loginPost(String username, String password){

        //Here a logging interceptor is created
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        //The logging interceptor will be added to the http client
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        //The Retrofit builder will have the client attached, in order to get connection logs
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
                .build(); Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

        Call<ServerResponse> call = service.post("login",username,password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ServerEvent(response.body()));
                Log.e(TAG,"Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ErrorEvent(-2,t.getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loginGet(String username, String password){
        //Here a logging interceptor is created
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        //The logging interceptor will be added to the http client
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        //The Retrofit builder will have the client attached, in order to get connection logs
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
                .build();

        Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

        Call<ServerResponse> call = service.get("login",username,password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ServerEvent(response.body()));
                Log.e(TAG,"Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ErrorEvent(-2,t.getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
```

both of top methods are used for send username and password to the server for authentication.

2-Second you should use communicator class inside your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Communicator communicator;
    private String username, password;
    private EditText usernameET, passwordET;
    private Button loginButtonPost, loginButtonGet;
    private TextView information, extraInformation;
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static Bus bus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        communicator = new Communicator();

        usernameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameInput);
        passwordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
        //This is used to hide the password's EditText characters. So we can avoid the different hint font.
      passwordET.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

        loginButtonPost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButtonPost);
        loginButtonPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = usernameET.getText().toString();
                password = passwordET.getText().toString();
                usePost(username, password);
            }
        });

        loginButtonGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButtonGet);
        loginButtonGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = usernameET.getText().toString();
                password = passwordET.getText().toString();
                useGet(username, password);
            }
        });

        information = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.information);
        extraInformation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraInformation);
    }

    private void usePost(String username, String password){
        communicator.loginPost(username, password);
        }

    private void useGet(String username, String password){
        communicator.loginGet(username, password);
    }
}
```

in the onCreate method we created an instance of communicator class and called useGet and usePost methods to send entered username and password to the server.

3-Don't forget to add library dependencies(add this codes into your build.gradle(Module:app) file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: are you sure this implementation is for providing socket programing?

Comment: No, Retrofit is only used for normal http connections. For socket connections I strongly suggest socket.io client. You can find more information here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Comment: so your answer is not for this answer and its wrong

Comment: this is just a normal http call